# How can i sort the record with paired rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

The format of the worksheet will like this. One Header + One Data

```
Name|Tel |Gender
May |123 |M
ID  |Name|Gender
1   |Tom |F
Name|Tel |Gender
Cho |123 |M
.......
```

2 rows as one record. I Want to sort by the first second rows. Like May,1,Cho
The result will become like this:

```
ID  |Name|Gender
1   |Tom |F
Name|Tel |Gender
Cho |123 |M
Name|Tel |Gender
May |123 |M
```

Any Excel function can do this?

Comment: That sort is not a sort at all. ID is not in order. Name is not in order. Gender is not in order. Not any column is sorted in your wish list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but there is no built-in option for that.

1. you need some helper columns

   - differentiate rows containing data and headers ("data row" column):
     `=MOD(ROW(),2)`
   - mark records ("record" column):
     `=INT(ROW()/2)`
   - after inserting these column, convert formulas to constants to avoid further updates:
     Select the new columns, copy them (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then insert as values (home - paste - special - values)
     [image]
2. sort data

   - first sort by "data row", in descending order, this will separate data from records, keeping data on top
   - next filter "data row" for `1`
   - then sort by first column, this will be the desired order of your records
3. merge records

   - remove filter
   - insert another helper column (new order), this will assign sequence number for data rows with the new ordering, and also manage headers, matching them to their original data:
     `=IF(D2=1,ROW()*2,SUMIFS(F:F,D:D,1,E:E,E2)-1)`
     [image]
   - convert this new column from formulas to constants like did for the previous helper columns
   - and finally sort by "new order" column
     [image]
   - and finally you can delete the helper columns

It may seems complicated, however, having a bit of practice even for 10 records it's quicker then sorting manually.